# How to implement "alsoLoad" with YAML mapping (Symfony)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I use Doctrine 2 as ODM (mongoDB) in Symfony framework. I have done a YAML-based mapping for entities and it works well.

But now, there is a field that has changed from "direction" to "destination", so I'm trying to use "alsoLoad" to keep it working with the data that is already stored, but it seems not to work properly : I keep seeing null in the destination field.

the doctrine mapping :

```
    fields:
      destination:
        type: string
        alsoLoad: direction
```

the serializer:

```
    destination:
        expose: true
```

Any clues? thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I can't see this mentioned in the docs, but [`HydratorFactory` will look for `alsoLoadFields` key](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/5e5e1fc9c8a17f972b125c80b9f9390e6171d662/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Hydrator/HydratorFactory.php#L184) in the mapping so try this:

```
fields:
  destination:
    type: string
    alsoLoadFields: [direction]
```